Logic and critical thinking
I'm a rising college freshman who's thinking of taking up philosophy as a major. However, I have a serious difficulty. I dont know how to argue, because I don't know how to think critically. I have won several debates at schools and I would actively engage in any discussions, but I face difficulty when it comes to critical thinking. And if I force myself to critically analyse something for an extended period, my head hurts. How do I tackle this? How do I think and analyse clearly?

Drink coffee. And if that doesn’t do the trick, move onto something stronger.

@dreamerinavoid How can you win debates without analyzing what your opponents say and without critical thinking and questioning? What is your strategy in rhetorics?

This website is not a good fit for such questions, maybe in chat somebody can answer. You need career counseling, life counseling or other counseling. This site is for questions about philosophic writers and their works.

The college bookshop or library or a local bookshop can all order books with titles including the main words from your question, if they don't already have some.  You could ask a professor to recommend a good one.  You can look at the arguments presented in the textbooks and reading materials in your courses and ask yourself what the writers are doing and what works' well (on you, for example).  Ask your professors to specifically focus the logic, analsys and critical thinking in your essays - they should to this anyway - and give you feedback and places to learn more.

Here are some thoughts about learning to philosophise and learning to think critically:
Read works by the great philosophers. They are great for a reason. Do your best to follow their arguments, and if you think they are wrong about something, try to articulate why they are wrong. Some of the subjects that philosophers argued about in the past may seem rather arcane, but the underlying themes of philosophical thinking have a way of resurfacing and remaining relevant.
Don't suppose that because some philosopher is highly regarded, everything they say is right. There have been many philosophical fashions and orthodoxies. Often it takes a whole generation before a popular philosophical theory is discarded. Equally, don't suppose that because some philosopher is ancient that what they have to say is out of date. There is plenty of wisdom in ancient authors.
Put your thoughts and ideas down in writing, with accompanying arguments, and get experienced and knowledgeable people to criticise them. In an academic course, this takes the form of writing essays and submitting them to your tutors. You cannot progress far just by reading; at some point you have to write and seek feedback. It is analogous to learning a foreign language: there is only so much you can learn from lectures and books. At some stage, you need to talk to people who are native speakers of the language and ask them to correct you. When you are starting out philosophising, this process is painful. Your initial essays will be rubbish and a good teacher will tell you so. It takes a great deal of work to develop critical faculties.
Study enough logic and probability theory to be able to identify poor quality inferences. Statistics are a particularly common source of bad reasoning, so it is important to know how to use them and how not use them.
Don't make the mistake of supposing that because you believe something then it must be true. Learn to criticise your own beliefs as impartially as you can manage. Most people tend to be wrong about a lot of things, a lot of the time. Look for evidence that you are wrong, rather than for evidence that you are right. Seek out the views of those who disagree with you. Try to spend more time reading and conversing with people of divergent views than with those you agree with. Don't assume that people who disagree with you have bad motivations. Social media has a strong tendency to present you with material from people who share your interests and opinions. Resist this tendency. Expand your horizons.
Don't be afraid to change your mind. It is natural to think of this as a weakness, but it is actually a sign that you are open to new ideas.
Don't be afraid to be undecided. You don't need to have a firm opinion on everthing.
Don't be afraid to go against the flow of current thought.
